# SELECT statement is MySql returning wrong value using python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to retrieve a value from a table stored in Mysql database using python(pycharm). But instead of outputting the stored value it outputs number of rows instead.

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='passw',
                             database='database1',
                             charset='utf8',
                             port=3306
                             )
x=connection.cursor()
select = x.execute('''SELECT
    update_id
FROM
    telegram;
''')
print(select)

Output: 1
```

^Wrong output(Output equals number of rows). As I keep adding on rows the output changes to the number of rows but never returns the value stored.

The command works from MySql perfectly.

```
SELECT
        update_id
    FROM
        telegram;
Output:233
```

^This is the correct output. 
Why is this happening? What changes should I make in my python code?

Comment: are you using the correct database??

Comment: Yes sir , The UPDATE command works using python on the same database and table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html) on pymysql, this is how you are supposed to do the print out:

```
    sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(result)
```

[image]

You are missing "cursor.fetchone()"

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html), cursor.execute() returns the number of affected rows.  You then need to fetch the content with fetch() or fetchall().  See the example at [PyMySQL](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/#documentation).

Comment: If you find one of the answers satisfactory, mark that answer "accepted" with the check mark.  It helps both you and me!